# 'const' keyword changing semantics

Tags: c++, constants

I attempted [today's leetcode challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/cousins-in-binary-tree/) in C++. You have to find cousins in a binary tree. Here's my code.

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

class Solution {
public:
    bool isCousins(TreeNode* root, int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        return visit(overloaded{
            [](const bool& r) { 
                return r; 
            },
            [](const optional<int>& r) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }, helper(root));
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;

    variant<const bool, optional<int>> helper(TreeNode* node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return variant<const bool, optional<int>>((optional<int>()));
        }
        else if (node->val == x) {
            return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(optional<int>(0));
        }
        else if (node->val == y) {
            return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(optional<int>(0));
        }
        else {
            auto l = helper(node -> left);
            auto r = helper(node -> right);
            return visit(overloaded{
                [](const bool& l, optional<int>& r) {
                    assert(!r.has_value());
                    return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(l); 
                },
                [](optional<int>& l, const bool& r) {
                    assert(!l.has_value());
                    return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(r); 
                },
                [](optional<int> l, optional<int> r) {
                    if (l.has_value() && r.has_value()) {
                        return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(*l > 0 && *l == *r);
                    }
                    else if (l.has_value()) { 
                        ++*l;
                        return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(l); 
                    }
                    else if (r.has_value()) { 
                        ++*r;
                        return variant<const bool, optional<int>>(r); 
                    }
                    else {
                        return variant<const bool, optional<int>>((optional<int>())); 
                    }
                }
            }, l, r);
        }
    }
};
```

A testcase that demonstrates my issue is

```
[1,3,2,null,null,7,4,null,null,5,6,null,8,null,9]
8
9
```

The code above runs and completes successfully. However, if I remove a single `const` keyword in line 10 (`[](bool& r) {`) then it returns a different (incorrect) answer. `const` is for compile-time safety, so shouldn't affect semantics, but I guess something strange is happening with `const` overloading? What's going on exactly?

Possibly related: it also breaks my mental model that if, instead of declaring `l`, `r`in lines 34,35, I pass them directly as arguments to visit (ie. `return visit(overloaded{..}, helper(node->left), helper(node->right)`), it also fails. I would again expect that to have no effect on semantics.

Comment: [mcve] would be helpful, because the code provided as-is does not compile.  I'm not sure why you'd expect changing the semantics would have no effect on the semantics.

Comment: you can copy and paste it into leetcode to have it compile. "I'm not sure why you'd expect changing the semantics would have no effect on the semantics. " <- I don't know why marking a lambda as "I guarantee I don't change this value" should make a difference to the return value, when it don't change the value regardless of whether it's marked as such.

Comment: Because taking away the const means the function is expecting an lvalue. Since the reference can't be constructed with a temporary bool then the other overload is called. You can construct a `const optional<int>&` from a `bool`. Const references can bind to temporaries.

Comment: Is there a reason you'e using such advanced concepts for this problem? Leetcode problems usually never necessitate the need for templates or `variant`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm used to functional programming, where this style .. has less friction. I guess at some point it became an experiment rather than "this must be the easiest way". (The template was just copied from an example somewhere).

Comment: If you used to a functional programming language, then functional programming in C++ is like doing object-oriented programming in C.  You can do it, the language is awkward at best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the `const` in this case changes the meaning of the code, by changing which function is selected in overload resolution.

Consider the following overload set and call:

```
void f(int const &) { std::cout << "i"; }
void f(bool) { std::cout << "b"; }

int main()
{
    int const i = 42;
    f(i); // prints i
    f(42); // prints i
}
```

both call the first function (as expected), because a `int const &` binds to a `int const`, as well as `int&&` (a temporary `int`).

However, if we remove the `const` in the first function of the overload set, and make the same call:

```
void f(int &) { std::cout << "i"; }
void f(bool) { std::cout << "b"; }

int main()
{
    int const i = 42;
    f(i); // prints b
    f(42); // prints b
}
```

the first function is not selected, because an `int &`, cannot bind to a `int const`. However, a `bool` can bind to an `int const`, (after an implicit conversion), and it calls the second function. Similarly, an `int &` cannot bind to a `int&&`, but a `bool` can, so it calls the second function.

This same reasoning applies to your example, but I've removed the `variant`, and custom overload set, as it simplifies the situation, without changing the underlying problem.